# Add a keyboard shortcut for the Keyboard input (<kbd>)

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts, kbd

Of all the tags here, typing the `<kbd></kbd>` keyboard input tags takes the longest, when writing answers or questions.  Could we please add a keyboard shortcut for this?  Similar features do exist, so it wouldn't be that hard to add, and it would save a lot of time.

This was [requested](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1454/please-add-a-toolbar-button-or-keyboard-shortcut-for-the-keyboard-style) and declined on Super User, on the grounds that it's used too sparingly, and would be too much work.  But similar features exist, so how hard could it be?  I use it fairly often when typing key names.

Comment: It actually takes the same amount of characters with `<sup></sup>` and `<sub></sub>`...

Comment: I know it is not the same as offical support but here is a related user script that would achieve that for now https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-superscript-and-subscript-markup-shortcuts